# How to Use Aspects in Fate Accelerated

Tags: character-creation, fate-accelerated, aspects

I recently got into playing and running Fate Accelerated, but there's one thing that's been confusing me, how the heck do you use Aspects?

I get that they're like characteristics of your character but the rules mention invoking them, and I'm not sure how all of that works.

Comment: Somewhat related on [New to fate - how to manage all aspects at play?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89004/new-to-fate-how-to-manage-all-aspects-at-play)

Comment: Have you read pages 25-30? That's the core section of Aspects and it is 10% of the entire book.

Comment: @Quentin Yes but I was still confused

Comment: @Gwideon — You might want to ask a more specific question about what you've read that you don't understand. As it is, this comes across as a request to [read the book to you](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/what-do-we-do-with-read-the-book-to-me-questions).

Answer (score 6):

I remembered that all of the information is available on the Fate SRD, so I pulled this from the section about [aspects and fate points](https://fate-srd.com/fate-accelerated/aspects-fate-points).

The book lists three options for Aspects:

- Invoke
- Compel
- Establish Facts

## Invoke to increase a roll (or hinder an opponent)

In my experience, 90% of the time or more, you're going to be using Invokes to give yourself a bonus to your roll.

- Add +2 to your roll (costs a fate point).
- Reroll the dice (costs a fate point).
- Help an ally (costs a fate point).
- Cause an opponent to have a confrontation (costs a fate point)

  - If there's an existing aspect that you think would hinder an opponent, you spend a fate point and their difficulty is increased by +2

Note: You can only invoke an aspect once on any given dice roll.

Note 2: Boosts from the advantage action or succeeding with style can be invoked once, and for free, then they vanish.

## Compelling Aspects

In my experience, this is usually going to be done by the GM (or storyteller).

Anyone can compel an aspect against you (even yourself - The Self Compel); they offer you a fate point and suggest the effect that the decision or event would have. Keep in mind that you can discuss and tweak the exact effect, but after a moment or two you need to decide whether or not to accept the compel. If you accept, you take the fate point and your character makes the suggested decision or the event happens. If you refuse, you must pay a Fate Point from your own supply.

Note: You cannot refuse a compel if you have no more Fate Points.

## Establishing Facts

Alright, I feel like this is a quarter of a use, more like a side effect, but it can have its own section.

Aspects can establish facts - about the environment, about a person, about the setting, etc. ***On Retainer for the Mob*** would suggest that you're a lawyer and that there is an active mob presence in this setting... and that you do work for them. ***Alien Girl on an Earth World*** tells us that the character is an alien, and that likely other aliens exist.

---

### Example:

The GM (or storyteller) wants to introduce dramatic tension, or advance the plot, or introduce something, etc; They offer the player a fatepoint to invoke one of their aspects.

Fighter McFighterson has the aspect "*Push WILL become shove*" and a confrontation is brewing after some punks in the local biker bar insult McFighterson's mother. The GM offers the player a Fate Point if McFighterson gives into the aforementioned aspect.

Fighter McFighterson gets into a bar brawl with some nasty folks and tries to break a chair over a miscellaneous bad guy, but he rolls poorly: 0,0,0,-1. He asks the GM if he can invoke his Aspect "*Push WILL become shove*" for a reroll; the GM accepts a Fate Point as payment and allows it to proceed. McFighterson rolls 1,1,0,0 - much better!